# Unknown Swift syntax

Tags: swift

I was just going through [this](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-01-23-lets-build-swift-notifications.html) blog from [Mikeash](https://mikeash.com) and found the following declaration:

```
private let f: AnyObject -> Parameters -> Void
```

I am not clear what this syntax means. I tried looking into Swift Programming Guide but was not able to find any answer.

Can someone please put some light on it, possibly some reference?

Comment: From the same blog: _You call the function and pass it an instance of the class, and it then returns a new function for the method that applies to that instance_

Comment: Yes, trying to grasp it, but still not clear. Swift syntax are sometime hard to digest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Swift Programming Language Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/function-type), Chapter *Types*, title *Function Types*:

> The function types of a curried function are grouped from right to left. For instance, the function type `Int -> Int -> Int` is understood as `Int -> (Int -> Int)` — that is, a function that takes an Int and returns another function that takes and return an Int. Curried function are described in Curried Functions.

(I formatted the code parts)

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID363) for an explanation about *curried functions*.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the type of `f` is a function which takes `AnyObject` as its parameter and returns a function which type is `Parameters -> Void`(takes `Parameters` as parameter and returns `Void`). Perhaps this code below will help you understand it.

```
func makeIncre(n:Int) -> Int -> Int {
    func addN(a:Int) -> Int{
        return a + n
   }
   return addN
}

let addOne = makeIncre(1)
let addTwo = makeIncre(2)

addOne(6) // 7
addTwo(6) // 8
```